# Set value of peoplepicker using javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have a newrequest.aspx page in a Sharepoint 2013 App with a form on it to get details from my users to submit a leave request,this is then submitted to a Sharepoint list to hold all of the requests for a workflow. On this form I have created a peoplepicker using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#manager").spPeoplePicker();
     });
</script>
```

Then in my .js file I have the following code to retrieve the values from that peoplepicker :

```
   var managerTitle = $("#manager_TopSpan_ResolvedList").find("span.ms-entity-resolved").attr("title");
```

Then I have the following code in the same .js file to submit these values to my list using javascript/ecmascript.(Note, I am only copying relevant code here, This all is part of a leave request app that I am busy with,so there is more fields in use but they all work fine)

Code:

```
var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Leave Requests");
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem.set_item("Manager", managerTitle);
oListItem.update();
context.load(oListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,       this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

The manager field chosen above is also a peoplepicker. I am looking for assistance to set that value. The code above gives an error by saying

> Invalid data was used to update the field or the field may be read-only

I have googled and tried a lot of different recommendations to no avail.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `oListItem.set_item("Manager", SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(managerTitle));` to set the person type field.

Comment: This is the exact answer that I was looking for! Thank you Sir! So simple. Just one thing, Remove the quotes around managerTitle.